# What is the copper pot that is kept hanging above the Shiva Lingam?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

In every Shiva temple, I have seen a copper pot (like the one in the picture) that is kept hanging above the Shiva Lingam. It has a hole at its bottom and is filled with water so that water keeps dripping on the Shiva Lingam. I have not noticed it being used for any other deity. Is there any particular reason for this water dripping copper pot being hanged above the Lingam?

[image]

<sup>Image source: http://www.indiamart.com</sup>

Comment: I read somewhere that lord Shiva is in deep meditation which makes his temperature increase (_hot_).. to keep him warm or normal, there should be always water or any other liquid form falling on the lingam. and even the surrounding of the temples should have water like pounds and water flow which helps in keeping the surroundings cool.

Answer (score 7):

Lord Shiva is very fond of [Abhishek](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2242/467). To make a continuous abhishek on the Shiv Ling, they put a copper pot which a very small hole at the bottom. This way water's abhishek runs for long period of time. Some people also put milk init.

Majority of Shivling worshipped in temples and sacred places have pots hanging on top of the Shivling. A hole is made on the pot and water drips continuously on the Shivling. There is a symbolism attached to the water dripping from the pot. Legend has it that the water in the pot is meant to cool Shiva of the effects of drinking the halahala poison during the Samudra Manthan.

Symbolically the water dripping from the pot indicates that life is always about movement. There is no stagnation. If we become stagnant then we rot and this is against nature.

Life also ebbs out slowly like the water dripping from the pot. The short period that is available should be used to attain self realization.

Each moment in our life is like the water drop, we should dedicate it to the supreme truth. Perform our dharma by submitting all actions to the supreme truth.

Comment: As far as i know..it is also said shiv linga must have something on top it, like rice,belpatra,flowers, etc.. what you hae to say about it @Kedarnath?

Comment: I imagine different people follow different rituals.

Answer (score 2):

Lord shiva also called as `jal dhar priya` (fond of small stream of water) so the copper pot filled with water is kept hanging above the Shiva Lingam..