# For how long has the tradition of pouring milk on shivling been going on?

Tags: history, shiva-lingam

Following on from [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/425/what-is-the-significance-of-pouring-milk-on-the-shivling),

- For how long has the tradition of pouring milk on the shivling been going on?
- What are the earliest historical records of such a practice?

Comment: So you don't want scriptural citations, you only want historical records?

Comment: I want to know when this custom started, according to the best evidence available. If someone could elaborate on how and why, that would be even better.