# Can we keep Shiva Linga at home?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

Can we keep the Siva Linga at home and is this good or bad for families? Some of the Lord Shiva's devotees are advising me to avoid the Shiva Linga to keep in home.

Comment: You can keep Shiva Linga at home only if you worship it with *Abhishekam* daily. If you are busy and if you have no time, then don't keep Shiva Linga in your house.  Pouring water on Linga is sufficient if you are busy. You must worship Shiva as you invited him into Linga by doing Prana Pratista.

Comment: Thanks. Prana Pratista means?

Comment: There are two types of Idols. Swayambhuva (Self Manifested) and non-Swayambhuva (Artificial idols). Swayambhuva idols have Consciousness (Shiva or God) in them but for Artificial idols we need to invite Lord into them and we worship that Lord in idols. So, we need to do [Prana Pratishta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prana_Pratishtha) (invite Shiva into that idol).

Comment: Get a banalinga.They are swayambhu.No need to invoke prana in them.And easy to get as well.For homes one should not buy a banaligna which is more than 3 fingers breadth.2/3 inches will be just fine.

Comment: oh yes you can keep. If thats a normal lingam there is no issues in keeping. But when it comes to SALIGRAMAM proper daily measures like abhisekam must be done. If a person is too busy to do abhisekam he can keep a shiva lingam in a bowl of rice. The strength of lingam is so powerful and thats why we have to do this. Saligramam is a lingam taken from a deep river or ganga or other holy river. So in order to maintain it we do abhisekam daily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Shiva Linga can be kept in your house but you must follow some rules to keep Shiva Linga in your house, as we invited Shiva into Linga by doing Prana Pratista.

[Dr.Annadanam Chidambara Sastri](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzTMgC3W7Q0) gives some instructions one must follow to keep Shiva Linga at home. This video is part of Telugu Program called Dharma Sandhehalu which is aired on Bhakti TV.

> Lord Shiva has two forms. Akalam and Sakalam. Akalam is Nirguna form
>   (unmanifested) which is worshiped in [Linga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14214/3500). Sakalam is manifested form
>   with Goddess Parvathi as Parameswara. It is said that by anointing
>   Shiva Linga with water and offering Bilva leaves to linga (placing
>   those leaves on top of Linga), we can tie Kamadhenu in our house.
>   There is no Dosham in keeping Shiva linga at home.
>
> It is suggested to do [Abhishekam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/425/3500) to linga and offer [Bilva leaves](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/873/3500)
>   daily. If you go to other place, you can immerse Shiva Linga in rice.
>   It's not mandatory to know [Namaka-Chamaka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11792/3500) Mantras (Sri Rudram) to do
>   Abhisheka but heartfelt Abhisheka with water is enough. Make sure the
>   Puja Room is clean and sacred.

Answer (score 2):

Shiva Linga can be kept in house. But you must follow some rules to keep Shiva Linga in your house.

Get up early in the morning , take bath, pluck flowers and first do linga pooja. You should do trikala pooja. This pooja is 3 times pooja  during a day.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.onlineprasad.com/parad-shiva-lingam-pooja-home/

visit this link to know what shiva lingam to worship at home.

Note: Parad shiva lingam doesn't need pran pratishta because it is believed that shiva is already present in mercury(shiv tatva).

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! We have to cite sources for our answers from authentic Hindu scriptures on this site.This is just link only answer in this case.Pls.provide answer refering to Authentic scriptures.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Bhubaneshwar , which is a Shaiva Pitha. The Lingaraj Temple is quite famous and devotees from all over India visit this Temple . A large number of Shiva Temples , have been built in Bhubaneshwar , between 8th Century AD to 11 th Century AD.
 We do keep Shiva Lingas at home for worship . There are no restrictions imposed on the worship of Shiva Linga . It is worsipped along with Images or Paintings of other Gods and Goddesses..
One thing , however, we are required to remember, is this -" SARVAM KHALU IDAM BRAHMAM "--God has transformed Himself into the whole Universe. " KA KAN MEIN BHAGAWAN" -is the equivalent in Hindi ..God exists in all atoms and particles in this Universe --is the meaning of this.

Comment: Who said there are no restrictions on Shiva linga worship? When you keep a linga at home, we must do Nitya poojas and naivedyam to it which might not be possible to some people. So all might not be able to do that.