# Question Regarding Shiva Linga?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam, puja

I have a shiv-Linga at home, which I think is made of ceramic material. I perform the puja by pouring simple tap water, then sandalwood tilak, then flowers and then dhoop/incense sticks.  I don't know whether the procedure is correct or not.

My 2nd question is - sometimes, due to my busy schedule, I forget to do abhishek of the lingam with water.

Is it good to keep the Lingam at home?  what does the Vedas quote about the practice of keeping shiv lingam at home?

Comment: Yes. You can keep Shiva Lingam in house. See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14589/3500). But try to do Abhisheka at least on Mondays. Also, use pure water instead of tap water.